# How to use Modernizr videoautoplaytest

Tags: modernizr

to find out if the browser supports videoautoplay, I use modernizr.

```
`https://codepen.io/handyaner/pen/NYgbzy`
```

but it always displays the text in green, which means autoplay is supported.
Even on an android smarphone. 
But on Android smartphones devintively no autoplay is supported.
Does anyone know why the test does not work correctly?

Comment: What is "this test"? You forgot to share your code

Comment: Does https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1095 help you? Have you tried researching the problem on your own?